# Creating new Workbook if a worksheet has data on it

Tags: excel, vba

Trying to create a new workbook only if a worksheet has data on it but am getting the error "Argument not optional" For the "CountA" Part

llllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllll

Edit New code:

```
Sub teststs()

If WorksheetFunction.CountA(Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("A1:AY300")) = 0 And Worksheets("Sheet2").Shapes.Count = 0 Then
    Worksheets("Sheet2").Delete

    Else
    Dim sWorkbook As Workbook

    'Create New Workbook
    Set sWorkbook = Workbooks.Add

    'Save Above Created New Workbook
    sWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:="C:\CODE\11 Production.xlsx"
    End If

If WorksheetFunction.CountA(Worksheets("Sheet3").Range("A1:AY300")) = 0 And Worksheets("Sheet3").Shapes.Count = 0 Then
    Worksheets("Sheet3").Delete

    Else
    Dim sWorkbook1 As Workbook

    'Create New Workbook
    Set sWorkbook1 = Workbooks.Add

    'Save Above Created New Workbook
    sWorkbook1.SaveAs Filename:="C:\CODE\22 Production.xlsx"
    End If

If WorksheetFunction.CountA(Worksheets("Sheet4").Range("A1:AY300")) = 0 And Worksheets("Sheet4").Shapes.Count = 0 Then
    Worksheets("Sheet4").Delete

    Else
    Dim sWorkbook2 As Workbook

    'Create New Workbook
    Set sWorkbook2 = Workbooks.Add

    'Save Above Created New Workbook
    sWorkbook2.SaveAs Filename:="C:\CODE\33 Production.xlsx"
    End If

If WorksheetFunction.CountA(Worksheets("Sheet5").Range("A1:AY300")) = 0 And Worksheets("Sheet5").Shapes.Count = 0 Then
    Worksheets("Sheet5").Delete

    Else
    Dim sWorkbook3 As Workbook

    'Create New Workbook
    Set sWorkbook3 = Workbooks.Add

    'Save Above Created New Workbook
    sWorkbook3.SaveAs Filename:="C:\CODE\44 Production.xlsx"
    End If

If WorksheetFunction.CountA(Worksheets("Sheet6").Range("A1:AY300")) = 0 And Worksheets("Sheet6").Shapes.Count = 0 Then
    Worksheets("Sheet6").Delete

    Else
    Dim sWorkbook4 As Workbook

    'Create New Workbook
    Set sWorkbook4 = Workbooks.Add

    'Save Above Created New Workbook
    sWorkbook4.SaveAs Filename:="C:\CODE\55 Production.xlsx"
    End If



End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

try like this

```
Sub tetstststs()

If WorksheetFunction.CountA(Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:M10")) = 0 And Worksheets("Sheet1").Shapes.Count = 0 Then
    Worksheet("Sheet1").Delete

    Else
    Dim sWorkbook As Workbook

    'Create New Workbook
    Set sWorkbook = Workbooks.Add

    'Save Above Created New Workbook
    sWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:="C:\CODE\Test.xlsx"
    End If

End Sub
```

Good luck

Comment: @matt.auerbach - please accept the answer if it has solved your problem.

Comment: @Luis Curado - i am now getting a problem when i try to use the function more than once. I renamed all the functions to have new names  but i still get the error Subscript out of range

Comment: The error is on the first line of the second If statement "If WorksheetFunction.CountA(Worksheets("Sheet3").Range("A1:AY300")) = 0 And Worksheets("Sheet3").Shapes.Count = 0 Then
    Worksheets("Sheet3").Delete"

Comment: ive tested and it works well. are u sure that are a sheet called "Sheet3" ?